# how to connect svn on ubuntu server with team development using zend studio?

Tags: svn, zend-framework, ubuntu

i have installed linux ubuntu on a local server then i installed the svn on it , now me and my team using zend studio 9.0.2 , and we need to work together on some project , can you help me with instruction how can that be done ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Zend with your  SVN repo is easy

```
File > New > Php Project From SVN
```

Hard part it is to setup your SVN repo in first place which is totally independent thing got nothing to do with zend studio . For how to setup SVN repo read http://svnbook.red-bean.com/